# Alternative formula in Excel 2003 for DSUM

Tags: formula, excel-2003

I am working with Excel 2003 and trying to find the total of individual criteria.  I am currently using this formula and it is working successfully.

Data A1:G1776 is the the database ---
Data C1 - is the column that has what I want total --- and 
F4:F5 is a column where I set up a the criteria for the line to match.

=DSUM(DATA!$A$1:$G$17996,DATA!$C$1,$F$4:F5)

The problem I am running into is that the file size is over 5MB, which is huge when you are trying to email it to other people.

Any suggestions how I can replicate that formula, while decrease the file size and also improving the speed of the document?  I am not wishing to use a Pivot Table

Answer (score 0):

A replacement for DSUM, you could use a sumproduct formula:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((DATA!$C$2:$C$17996)*(DATA!$A$2:$A$17996="Boys")*(DATA!$B$2:$B17996>18))
```

The above example creates a total of column C only including rows where: Column A are "boys and column B is greater than 18. 
The example assumes that row 1 is a header row.

For speeding up calculations you could use VBA to enable calculation of indvidual sheets.

VBA for enabling calculation:

```
Public Sub enableCalc(ParamArray sheetsInUse())
  Dim i As Integer
  For i = 0 To UBound(sheetsInUse) Step 1
      sheetsInUse(i).EnableCalculation = True
  Next i
End Sub
```

Called using: enableCalc activeworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Which would enable calculation Sheet1 in the activeworkbook

VBA for disabling calculation for all sheets in workbook:

```
Public Sub finishedUse(wrkbook As Workbook)
Dim i As Integer
Dim wrkSheet As Worksheet
For Each wrkSheet In wrkbook.Worksheets
wrkSheet.EnableCalculation = False
Next wrkSheet
End Sub
```

Called using: finishedUse activeworkbook
Which would disable calculation of all the sheets in the activeworkbook.

The above method isnt effected by changing Automatic/Manual Calculation in Tools --> Options